# May I (somehow) mention resources in tfvars?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I use [terraform-aws-cloudfront module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-cloudfront) and I'd like to call my module like this:

```
main.tf

module "cloudfront" {
  source                        = "./cloudfront-module"
  create_distribution           = var.cf_create_distribution
  aliases                       = var.cf_aliases
  enabled                       = var.cf_enabled
  default_root_object           = var.cf_default_root_object
  create_origin_access_identity = var.cf_create_origin_access_identity
  origin_access_identities      = var.cf_origin_access_identities
  origin                        = var.cf_origin
  custom_error_response         = var.cf_custom_error_response
  geo_restriction               = var.cf_geo_restriction
  default_cache_behavior        = var.cf_default_cache_behavior
  viewer_certificate            = var.cf_viewer_certificate
}
```

```
.tfvars

...
cf_default_cache_behavior        = {
                                      target_origin_id           = "${local.bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com" 
                                      viewer_protocol_policy     = "redirect-to-https" 
                                      allowed_methods            = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"] 
                                      cached_methods             = ["GET", "HEAD"] 
                                      compress                   = true 
                                      cache_policy_id            = data.aws_cloudfront_cache_policy.this.id 
                                      use_forwarded_values       = false
                                      response_headers_policy_id = "67f7725c-6f97-4210-82d7-5512b31e9d03"
                                    }

 cf_viewer_certificate            =  { 
                                       acm_certificate_arn=aws_acm_certificate.this.arn 
                                       ssl_support_method="sni-only"
                                     }
...
```

but I've got a problem:

```
output

Error: Variables not allowed
  on ./config/some.tfvars line 30:
  30:                                      cache_policy_id            = data.aws_cloudfront_cache_policy.this.id 
Variables may not be used here.
Error: Variables not allowed
  on ./config/some.tfvars line 47:
  47:                                       acm_certificate_arn=aws_acm_certificate.this.arn 
Variables may not be used here.
```

Is there a workaround if I want to mention resources attributes that will be deployed before they actually deployed in .tfvars?

Comment: You could instead use `locals` block which would get the value from e.g., a data source or a an attribute exported from a resource that was previously created, but I'm not sure if that is your question.

Comment: @MarkoE my question was: "How could I get rid of these errors regarding "variables not allowed here" and keep all those values in .tfvars like I wanted to?"

Comment: You an hard-code them or rewrite the module, according to what I see. Or maybe use locals instead of all the variables and then you would be able to use even the exported attributes without any issues.

Comment: Yea, thanks! I've already found that I could easily place those values in module call and then everything would work as intended, but I really wanted to keep my module call clean as I mentioned in post, using only variables. I hoped that there is some different ways to achieve my goal I'm not awared of, but seems like it's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables) are for passing data from outside of the module, not for deriving values from other data inside the module.

The typical way to achieve a result like you've described is to use [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals). There is no way to use input variables as if they were local values, because these are two separate features each with their own intended purpose.

The documentation describes the relationship between these concepts by analogy to functions in a general purpose language:

> - Input variables are like function arguments.
> - Output values are like function return values.
> - Local values are like a function's temporary local variables.

If there isn't any need for someone running this configuration to customize these values then you could just take the contents of your `.tfvars` file exactly as you wrote it and place it inside a `locals` block to declare local values that represent that data:

```
locals {
  cf_default_cache_behavior = {
    target_origin_id           = "${local.bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com" 
    viewer_protocol_policy     = "redirect-to-https" 
    allowed_methods            = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"] 
    cached_methods             = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    compress                   = true 
    cache_policy_id            = data.aws_cloudfront_cache_policy.this.id 
    use_forwarded_values       = false
    response_headers_policy_id = "67f7725c-6f97-4210-82d7-5512b31e9d03"
  }

  cf_viewer_certificate = { 
    acm_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.this.arn 
    ssl_support_method  = "sni-only"
  }
}
```

These would then be `local.cf_default_cache_behavior` and `local.cf_viewer_certificate` when used elsewhere in your module, such as in your call to the other module:

```
module "cloudfront" {
  # ...
  default_cache_behavior = local.cf_default_cache_behavior
  # ..
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you wish to combine values provided by the caller of your module with values defined within your module then you can instead derive the local values *from* the input variables, adding the extra attributes that will be decided dynamically:

```
locals {
  cf_default_cache_behavior = merge(var.cf_default_cache_behavior, {
    cache_policy_id = data.aws_cloudfront_cache_policy.this.id 
  })

  cf_viewer_certificate = merge(var.cf_viewer_certificate, {
    acm_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.this.arn
  })
}
```

The above assumes that you still have the `variable "cf_default_cache_behavior"` and `variable "cf_viewer_certificate"` blocks, but that you remove the `cache_policy_id` and `acm_certificate_arn` attributes from their type constraints because those attributes in particular will be added by your module, rather than provided by the caller.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that! I've already came up with the first solution, but alternative one seems really interesting and I guess it is what I've been looking for!